# Sumar valor de 2 funciones

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy intentado sumar el valor de 2 funciones en una hoja de cálculo de Google.
La función en si lo que hace es sumar los valores que sólo están en el color que se le pasa como referencia.
La fórmula es esta.

```
sumColoredCells(E4:E34;D36)
```

Mi intención es sumar el valor de esa fórmula, con el valor de otra igual pero seleccionando otras columnas.
Esto es lo que he intentado.

```
=SUM(sumColoredCells(E4:E34;D36);sumColoredCells(G4:G34;D36))
```

Me sale **#ERROR!**.

Espero que alguien me pueda echar una mano con esta suma. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Prueba con `sumColoredCells(E4:E34;D36) + sumColoredCells(G4:G34;D36)` SUM creo recordar que era solo para rangos.

Comment: @JDev Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo he probado y no funciona.

Comment: Quizás no sea el mejor método pero puedes realizar las dos sumas por separado y en otra celda sumar los dos resultados, por ejemplo: en D37 `=sumColoredCells(E4:E34;D36)` en D38 `=sumColoredCells(G4:G34;D36)`y en D39 `=D37+D38`

Comment: @YESIDDOTNET si, así lo tengo ahora. Buscaba la manera de sumar el valor de las 2 funciones en una misma celda. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: La pregunta no es clara porque el mensaje de error está incompleto porque aunque se muestra el mensaje mostrado como valor, faltó incluir el mensaje emergente que se muestra al pasar el puntero sobre el triángulo rojo. Por otro lado la función sumColoredRed es una función personalizada pero no se incluye el código de la misma, lo cual es necesario para reproducir el problema.